# What exact rights I'm giving to Uniswap when accepting "Allow the Uniswap Protocol to use your XXX"

Tags: metamask, uniswap, swaps

When trying for the first time to swap between 2 tokens with a given ETH wallet you get the message *"Allow the Uniswap Protocol to use your XXX"* (XXX is whatever token):

[image: Uniswap asking to use your token]

Clicking in the (?) icon there is not much explanation what it means to "use" your token:

[image: Uniswap explanation when asking token access]

And clicking the "Allow the Uniswap..." button having a MetaMask wallet connected this is the explanation from the wallet:

[image: Metamask confirmation]

I know this is only asked one time per token, and it's useful to e.g. prevent phishing attacks where I'm in a page that is not the XXX token contract but pretends to be... but my question is not *why* but *what*.

If I click the approval can Uniswap later take from my wallet (e.g. BUSD) my BUSD funds without my approval? it's a technical question, not whether Uniswap is going to do that in reality, but if so, and Uniswap is hacked in some way, whether the hackers could withdraw my funds without having my private key from my wallet just because I've signed this approval before.

Note aside, I think they should explain better what means the approval in the swap dialog (*they* = *Uniswap* and *MetaMask*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary

ERC-20 compatible tokens have an "approve" function that lets the approved transfer them until the approved amount is moved. See below for "why we need the approve function".

**This means, once you approve another address to do something with your tokens, they can do at anytime they wish. They are only stopped given access if you do one of the following:**

- You revoke the approval (in another TX)
- They run out of allowance

  - (for example, if you allow them to have access to 2 tokens and they move 2 tokens, their allowance is expired)

When you allow the Uniswap contract permission, you give Uniswap the ability to move your tokens. Often, this is so the contract will know that you want to swap your tokens, and can route them accordingly.

**The contract pulls your tokens from your wallet, as opposed to you pushing your tokens into the contract.** But in order for them to pull the tokens, you have to give it approval to.

This is safe for Uniswap because that the time of my writing, the Uniswap contract doesn't have the ability to do something malicious with your tokens by itself or another actor.

## Going granular

We can look at the full transaction details to break down precisely what happens when you approve ERC20-compatible tokens.

Here is an example Metamask:

[image]

And here is our full transaction details (hit the full transactions details button and then scroll to the bottom to see).

```
0x095ea7b30000000000000000000000004ca6e59a1a0a5608d23cce80c0def1d74a1b46ea0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000
```

[image]

You can see here exactly what is happening in this example. We approve the address in `Granted to` to transfer our ERC-20 tokens. And the approved amount you can see in the `Approved amount` section.

### Why do we need an approve function?

Every ERC-20 token has an "approve" function. This function allows other addresses to transfer your tokens. The reason we need this, is many protocols need to pull the funds from your wallet so they can register you sending the money to them. If you just "send the money" the contracts won't always know what it's for.

### More information

To go more granular, we can break down the TX details exactly:

- `0x095ea7b3`: The `approve` function selector, so we know which function to call in our TX.
- `4ca6e59a1a0a5608d23cce80c0def1d74a1b46ea`: The address of the `approved`
- `de0b6b3a7640000`: The hex of `1 LINK` (1000000000000000000)

(and some zeros in the TX data as well for solidity reasons)

Comment: I like this answer (you're a G), but wouldn't it be more succinct to say: 

> If I click the approval can Uniswap later take from my wallet (e.g. BUSD) my BUSD funds without my approval?

`The Uniswap contract you are approving can only **take** from your wallet if they have a function that can be called by others (not your wallet) that transfers your token without you initiating the transfer. In the case of uniswap's contracts this condition does not exist, but you should always verify the contracts you are approving.`

What do you think?

Comment: "If I approve Uniswap can take from my wallet without my approval" - I'm not sure that makes sense. You approving Uniswap is giving the Uniswap approval to take your funds. Maybe instead of "approval" you can use the word "prompt"? "You should check before approval what functions in the contract can do. In Uniswap's example, they can only take your funds when you prompt it to with another transaction after approval".

Comment: Thanks @patrick-collins for all the technical details, it's very useful specially the message details. Still from the perspective of a wallet holder not a developer it's not clear what Uniswap can do after, regardless of their willingness to do something they shouldn't or not. So the main question is: if I approve Uniswap to access my XXX tokens, can they, 1 hour later, 2 days after or whatever time, without my later consent, take from my XXX wallet part or all of my funds?

Comment: Following @BigRon comments looks like it's not possible because a lack of a function implementation, right? if so, how can I check the same from other contracts I want to interact with?

Comment: I updated the answer, does that make it clearer? They can do literally anything with your tokens once you approve.

Comment: > "how can I check the same from other contracts I want to interact with"
How can you check what?

Comment: @PatrickCollins "They can do literally anything with your tokens once you approve."
Maybe I'm bikeshedding, but I think it's important for people to understand a nuance here. I think it's more accurate to say: "They can do literally anything *that their (Uniswap) contract allows* with your tokens once you approve. *In the case of Uniswap there is no arbitrary transfer function that could be called at some future date. So they can't do anything unintended. On the other hand if you approved an EOA to transfer your tokens then they could transfer at will at any time.*"

Comment: Thanks Patrick , very useful ! So in the case of Uniswap they can't because they don't have a method to call later a withdraw, but with other contracts depending of the code would be possible. Right? What you mean with "EOA"?

Comment: You got it @MarianoRuiz. This is why it's important to keep your approvals down, if you don't know every inch of the code it might have a function that can pull your funds! An EOA stands for "Externally Owned Account" and just means it's an ETH address that doesn't have any code associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're giving the rights to Uniswap to authorize the transaction, which includes approving the tokens to be spent and swapping the tokens.

Approvals are considered an industry standard across all decentralized exchanges (like Uniswap, PancakeSwap, CowSwap ... etc.), and protect your wallet from being accessed by a smart contract without your permission. By design, smart contracts can’t access your tokens unless you approve access from your end. Once you have successfully approved your tokens to be used with a contract you won't need to approve them again.

Comment: Thanks, still I don't know what are exactly the rights given to Uniswap.